# iOS App Distribution Private to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have created app on App Store Connect then selected Pricing and Availability there in bottom three options are available.

I need to deploy my app for an oraganization, also my application has frequent chnages.So need private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager  without any App Review Process.

But as i checked below option need to be selected --
**Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager**

In my case above option selection button is disable. Is there any information missing from my side please suggest the solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read online the following, I hope it helps;

[Source](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001578499-Publishing-a-private-iOS-app-via-Apple-Business-Manager)
[image]

Comment: Tck13 Thanks! Could you please let me know next steps after this process. How the organization devices would get register with ABM.